# Select2: How to unselect all options and select only one

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I’m using `Select2`, a great plugin.

HTML:

```html
<select id="fruits" multiple="true">
  <option value=''>All
  <option value='Apple'>Apple
  <option value='Pear'>Pear
  ...
```

JavaScript:

```js
$('#fruits').select2();
```

When I select the “All” option, I need to unselect all previously selected options and have only the “All” option selected.

I’ve tried

```js
onChange="$('#fruits').select2('val', ['All']);"
```

as well as

```js
onChange="$('#fruits').select2('data', ['All']);"
```

but it does not seem to work for me.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this fiddle with my code, try this...

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vyZDq/24/)

It is based on click event.

```
$(function() {
    $('#fruits').click(function(e) {
        var selected = $(e.target).val();
        if(selected=='all'){
           $('#fruits > option').prop("selected",false);
           $(e.target).prop("selected",true);
        };
    }); 
});
```

Comment: It would make others including me happy if you share your working solution... The one in accepted answer definitely does not work.

Comment: can you please tell me what didn't work for you... i guess OP got the thing he wanted... if you select ALL everything else will be unselected if you check in the fiddle

Answer (score 4):

This is correct. This code worked for me properly.

```
$('#selectId').select2('val',"");
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

1)For unselecting selected item.

```
$("#fruits option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

2)for selecting all

```
 $('#fruits option:[text="All"]').attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $("#fruits option:selected").removeAttr("selected");

 $("#fruits option[value='']").attr("selected","selected");
```